# Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "?"

Tags: templating

We’re running into issues with the null coalescence operator in the latest version of Craft (2.6.2989).

[image]

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Where are getting this error?  In the Control Panel somewhere?

Comment: Also, what version of PHP are you running?

Comment: That's in the CP. Currently on PHP 7.0.10, however, it's also present on PHP 7.1.

Comment: That's... odd.  Going to respond from your support ticket and will follow up here with any solution.

Comment: Things to try: 1. Re-download Craft and replace the /app folder. 2. Disable all plugins; if the error goes away; re-enable the plugins one by one.

Comment: Also, what @MatsMikkelRummelhoff said.

Comment: Thanks, both. Have tried both of those steps already. Brad, I'll respond to your email.

Comment: Sorry, @Mats; You were right! I hadn’t properly disabled all plugins, it seems. Removing plugins via the database one by one _did_ root out the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was a plugin’s `composer.json` that was loading an older version of Twig as a nested dependancy, which was overriding Craft’s Twig.

Running a `composer update` for that plugin rectified the issue.